# C library to read from zip archives

Tags: c, zip

Is there a portable C library to access .zip archives? "gzip" or "zlib" (the closest I could find) only handle compressed data, I need to be able to list the files inside the archive, and access each one individually, and if they're compressed using the 'deflate' method, I can use zlib on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minizip, maybe?

http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html

Answer (score 1):

The zip that comes with Linux and BSD is actually called info-ZIP which is [here](http://www.info-zip.org/).  Personally I have not tried such a thing but the info-zip front page states "Info-ZIP's primary compression engine has also been spun off into the free zlib compression library", so you might want to check out zlib.  The zlib page has a FAQ with a answer to your specific question.  I would start by studying how info-zip works.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

7-zip has a complete SDK, with example sources, and a lot of functionality.

take a look [here](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)